# Function seems to make zero a variable in C and 'flush' previous variable

Tags: c, function

In this program the objective is to create an evaluation of workers to catalogue them by risk factor. I have declared a function to evaluate every one of the questions that would make the profile of the workers.

The thing is, I don't know what went wrong while declaring the function, and I don't even know if that's exactly the problem.

My code goes well up to statements about "peso" and the program succesfully asks the user the value and also seems to be stored inside the variable. But, when the function is called to be assigned to the diabetes variable the value of peso becomes zero and then, when the function is called again to be assigned to hipert, the diabetes value seems to flush, because it wouldn't print it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char resp(char tempo[1], char op_1[1], char op_2[1]);

int main(void){
    char sexo[1];
    int edad;
    int peso;
    char pre[0];
    char diabetes[1];
    char hipert[1];
    
    printf("Calculadora de factor de riesgo - COVID19.\n");
    printf("Ingresa los datos que se te pidan.\n");
    printf("Ingresa tu sexo (m/f): ");
    sexo[0] = resp(sexo, "m", "f");
    
    printf("\nIngresa tu edad (mayor o igual a 18): ");
    scanf("%d", &edad);
    while(edad<18){
        printf("\nRespuesta no aceptada. Intenta de nuevo. ");
        scanf("%d", &edad);
    }
    
    printf("\nIngresa tu estado de peso (bajo (1), normal (2), sobrepeso (3), obesidad (4)): ");
    scanf("%d", &peso);
    while(peso != 1 && peso != 2 && peso != 3 && peso != 4){
        printf("\nRespuesta no aceptada. Intenta de nuevo. ");
        scanf("%d", &peso);
    }
    
    printf("\nPadeces diabetes? (s/n): ");
    diabetes[0] = resp(diabetes, "s", "n");
    
    printf("\nPadeces hipertension? (s/n): ");
    hipert[0] = resp(hipert, "s", "n");
    
    printf("%s", sexo);
    printf("%d", edad);
    printf("%d", peso);
    printf("%s", diabetes);
    printf("%s", hipert);
    
}

char resp(char tempo[1], char op_1[1], char op_2[1]){
    scanf("%s", &tempo[0]);
    while (tempo[0] != op_1[0] && tempo[0] != op_2[0]){
        printf("\nRespuesta no aceptada. Intenta de nuevo. ");
        scanf("%s", &tempo[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The arrays of length 1 are very strange.  If you want a single `char`, why not pass a `char`?  The array of length 0 is even stranger (but apparently never used, luckily).

Comment: In particular `scanf("%s", &tempo[0]);` in `resp` is very wrong because `scanf` may store any number of characters, plus one more for a trailing null, and you only have space for 1 total.  Perhaps you wanted that to be a `%c`, though then you will have a little more work to do in skipping whitespace.

Comment: Sorry, that pre[0] array was an experiment that clearly didn't work. And, what do you mean by passing them as a char? Just write "char sexo;"?

Comment: @NateEldredge The additional work to skip whitespace should be adding a space before `%c` in the format string.

Comment: There is no such thing as flushing a variable. DIfficult to know what you're talking about really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `sexo` (passed as `tempo`) has only one element, so it can store only upto zero-character string (plus terminating null-character) and passing it for `%s` is dangerous.
- return value of `resp` is assigned to `sexo[0]`, but no `return` statement is in `resp` and using its return value will invoke *undefined behavior*.

To fix, at least the lines

```
char sexo[1];
char diabetes[1];
char hipert[1];
sexo[0] = resp(sexo, "m", "f");
diabetes[0] = resp(diabetes, "s", "n");
hipert[0] = resp(hipert, "s", "n");
```

should be

```
char sexo[2];
char diabetes[2];
char hipert[2];
resp(sexo, "m", "f");
resp(diabetes, "s", "n");
resp(hipert, "s", "n");
```

Also there are more points to improve such as:

- Length to scan should be limited: `%1s` instead of `%s` for `scanf()`.
- Return values of `scanf()` should be checked.
- Return type of `resp()` should be `void` to mark that the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: It worked! But know I have a lot more of doubts. I understand that the char variables must be declared with up to two values, because the null-character occupy one of those spaces. But, why passing it as a %s is dangerous?

What do you mean with scanf should be checked?

Comment: Using one-element `char` array for `%s` will lead to buffer overrun when any positive-length string is read, so very dangerous. Also generally using `%s` is dangerous because buffer size is limited while the maximum length to read is unlimited, so it may cause buffer overrun when long enough string is read.